Preventing Automatic Extension of Selection Range to Adjacent Divs
I have a number of consecutive DOM divs that contain text.
I created the following function to get the selected divs
When I select multiple consecutive divs by triple clicking their text in the browser, the function returns the selected divs as well as the next one that I haven't selected.
Probably this is due to the browser's behavior, but is there a workaround?


function get_selected_sentences_range() {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var sentences_obj;
  var sentences_order_range = [];
  if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedNode = range.startContainer;
    while (selectedNode && selectedNode.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      selectedNode = selectedNode.parentNode;
    }
    //if the cursor is at one of the .sentences_container children
    if ($(selectedNode).parents(".sentences_container").length > 0) {
      sentences_obj = $(".sentences_container").find(".sentence_div").filter(function() {
        //check if the selection contains this element
        if (selection.containsNode(this, true)) {
          //but if the selected text is only an end-of-paragraph character, don't include it
          if (selection.toString().trim() == "") {
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  sentences_obj.each(function(n) {
    var this_sentence_order = $(this).attr("data-sentence-order");
    if (n == 0) { //the first selected element
      sentences_order_range.push(this_sentence_order);
    }
    //if it's the last element
    if (n == sentences_obj.length - 1) {
      sentences_order_range.push(this_sentence_order);
    }
  });
  return sentences_order_range;
}
    $(".sentences_container").on("mouseup", ".sentence_div", function(e){
        var selected_sentences_range = get_selected_sentences_range();
        $("#selection").html("Selected sentences are: "+selected_sentences_range[0]+", and: "+selected_sentences_range[1]);
    });
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sentences_container" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="sentence_div" contenteditable="true" data-sentence-order="1">This is sentence number 1.</div>
    <div class="sentence_div" contenteditable="true" data-sentence-order="2">This is sentence number 2.</div>
    <div class="sentence_div" contenteditable="true" data-sentence-order="3">This is sentence number 3.</div>
    <div class="sentence_div" contenteditable="true" data-sentence-order="4">This is sentence number 4.</div>
    <div class="sentence_div" contenteditable="true" data-sentence-order="5">This is sentence number 5.</div>
    <div class="sentence_div" contenteditable="true" data-sentence-order="6">This is sentence number 6.</div>
</div>
<div id="selection"></div>




Please convert your code into a runnable snippet so that we can see the issue.

How to trigger the behaviour you see?

I refined the snippet again. If you triple-click the first 2 sentences, let say, it will say in the result div (".selection") that even the third one is selected.
